# Derivative of a trigonometric function with pulsation

Tags: calculus, derivatives, trigonometry

I'm sure I'm just blanking, but what is the rule that allows me to extract $\pi$ from the parameter, such that:
$$\frac{d}{d\theta} \cos(\pi \theta) = -\pi\sin(\pi\theta)$$

I do know that $\frac{d}{d\theta}\cos\theta = -\sin\theta$, but am completely blanking on the, presumably, trigonometric rule permitting the former. Any help would be grand.

Thanks, 
P

Comment: It's the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule). $\frac{d}{d\theta}\cos(\pi\theta)=-\sin(\pi\theta)\frac{d}{d\theta}(\pi\theta)$

Comment: In general, $\frac d{dx}[f(g(x))] = f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)$

Comment: I took the liberty of changing the word *complex* to *complicated* in the question's title.  The word *complex* in this context often suggests Complex Analysis, rather than Real Analysis, and the question is clearly focusing only on Real Analysis.

Comment: If the Q&A is quite trivial, I don't think anyone minds if you just delete the Question for the sake of decluttering the database. Likewise for your first question on this site. -)